# When my chapter gets longer than 1 page, the page numbering will start in the top corner left

Tags: table-of-contents

I have this new template for my table of contens, but when my chapter get more than 1 page long, the next pages will have their pagenumbering on the top. Is there anyway I could change this to the bottom? Also my chaptername is standing on the top of the page, I dont want to delete this yet, but it could be nice if you could tell me which command is doing that either.

```
\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{127,0,0}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{169,121,69}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\sffamily\contentsname}{}{}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{127,0,0}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{169,121,69}

%\renewenvironment{leftbar}{%
%  \def\FrameCommand{{\color{myyellow}\vrule width 2pt depth 6pt} \hspace{10pt}}%
%  \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
% {\endMakeFramed}

\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addtocontents{toc}%
                                   {%
                                       {\noindent\protect\parbox{3.8em}{\hfill\Huge\color{myred}\bfseries\thepage}}%
                                         \protect\hspace*{.5em}%
                                        \protect\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-4.5em\relax}{%
                                           \protect\begin{leftbar}
                                              {\scshape\small\chaptername~\thechapter}\\\sffamily#1%
                                           \protect\end{leftbar}}\par%\noindent
                                    }%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\makeatother
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\renewenvironment{leftbar}
  {\def\FrameCommand{\hspace{6em}%
    {\color{myyellow}\vrule width 2pt depth 6pt}\hspace{1em}}%
    \MakeFramed{\parshape 1 0cm \dimexpr\textwidth-6em\relax\FrameRestore}\vskip2pt%
  }
 {\endMakeFramed}

\titlecontents{section}
  [8.4em]
  {\sffamily\contentslabel{3em}}{}{}
  {\hspace{0.5em}\nobreak\itshape\color{myred}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}
  [8.4em]
  {\sffamily\contentslabel{3em}}{}{}  
  {\hspace{0.5em}\nobreak\itshape\color{myred}\contentspage}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter {one}
hello
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: You will have both page number in the footer, and no chapter title in the header) if you declare in the preamble: `\pagestyle{plain}`.

Comment: The page style of the first page of any chapter is `plain`. If that's the style you want applied everywhere, add `\pagestyle{plain}` right after `\begin{document}`. Adding it there enables the page style for your chapters and your ToC.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add

```
\pagestyle{plain}
```

to your preamble:

[image]